# Linkedin API (v2) 5xx Errors to get organizationalEntityShareStatistics

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm facing problems with my client because I can't get the share's statistics for his organization.

Since December 2021 the API is returning Internal Server Error for many request in the `organizationalEntityShareStatistics` endpoint.
[API analytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSLD2.png)

The request works for other organizations.

I have tried reaching Linkedin through their support pages but they have told me to post it here on stack overflow; In this private support request I show the app tokens used: https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/26241?page=1 or here: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/cases/39424961

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedIn answered me that I should filter some posts, according to their "lifecycleState" field, which for some cases make the request fail, they should only be PUBLISHED or PUBLISHED_EDITED